# How to get the data type of a list item field?

Tags: 2013

i am using CSOM 2013 and need the required data type of a ListItem-field.
Who can help?

Comment: Did you mean content type of item?

Comment: No, the data type of a field in a list.

Comment: So, the SPFieldType of the field?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question in order for us to help answer your query.

Answer (score 1):

The client library does not know the real type of the returned object "field" and SharePoint.Field is the only possible type. If you know the real type, you can use the ClientContext.CastTo method to cast the object.

For Example

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 
SP.List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements"); 
SP.Field field = list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field DisplayName='MyField2' Type='Number' />", 
                                           true, 
                                           AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue); 
SP.FieldNumber fldNumber = context.CastTo<FieldNumber>(field); 
fldNumber.MaximumValue = 100; 
fldNumber.MinimumValue = 35; 
fldNumber.Update(); 

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Many examples using CSOM can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx)

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer.
I'm not sure if we mean the same.
I think this example is better for me:

SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[Id].Fields[Id].TypeAsString

Answer (score 1):

You must get all fields using list.get_fields() then foreach field from collection get field type using  var fType = oField.get_fieldTypeKind();

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
        this.listFields = list.get_fields();
        clientContext.load(this.listFields);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, 
            this.onListFieldsQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, 
            this.onListFieldsQueryFailed));

        function onListFieldsQuerySucceeded() {
            var fieldEnumerator = listFields.getEnumerator();
            while (fieldEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oField = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
                var fType = oField.get_fieldTypeKind();
                if(fType === SP.FieldType.choice) {
                   .....
                }
            }
        }
```

[Link to source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/26289/20912)

Comment: Please add some text to your answer, indicating what the code does and how to use it :)